# Potential Function Runtime

Tags: functions, algorithms, fibonacci-numbers

The potential function of a Fibonacci Heap is

```
Φ(H) = t(H) + 2m(H)
```

[CLRS](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap21.htm) states in Figure 21.2

```
To determine the cost, let H be the input Fibonacci heap and H' be the 
resulting Fibonacci heap. Then, t(H') = t(H) + 
1 and m(H') = m(H), and the increase in potential is 
((t(H) + 1) + 2m(H)) - (t(H) + 2m(H)) = 1 .
```

It seems like we do H' - H and get 1. But what if the potential function was Φ(H) = 2t(H) + m(H)? How can I setup the equation to get the runtime then? Would it be

```
(2t(H) + 1) + m(H)) - (2t(H) + m(H)) = 1?
```